# Unable to access scriptlet variable from inside Struts 2 tag

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, scriptlet

I am trying to access a scriptlet variable inside a struts2 `s:if` tag in my JSP

```
<%
Website website = (Website)request.getAttribute(Website.NAME);
out.println(website.isUkSite());  // prints true
 %>

<s:if test="#website.isIrishSite()">  // this is returning false 
....
```

actually this `s:if` should evaluate to `true`. What is the issue ?

Comment: Don't use scriptlets.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is there's no variable named `website` in the action context. To make it working you might use

```
<%
Website website = (Website)request.getAttribute(Website.NAME);
out.println(website.isUkSite());  // prints true

ActionContext.getContext().put("website", website); 
 %>
```

But scriplets is a bad choice, you could remove this code and use

```
<s:if test="#request.website.isIrishSite()">
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked finally

```
<%
Website website = (Website)request.getAttribute(Website.NAME);
out.println(website.isUkSite());  // prints true
 %>

<s:if test="website.ukSite">    
  // this is executed finally !!
</s:if>
```